# Querying A table including 0 value my sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to query a location based hierarchy data. But I am having trouble on how to do the approach for querying the data. Here is a sample data for my database.

[image]

Now, I want to query a product based from location filter. so if I am going to select a product with a country_id of 7 and a state of 1. It will fetch all countries with a value of 7 and all state with a value of 1 but it will also include all state with an id of 0 since it not assigned on any state. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: If `state` only has 0 or 1, you can use this `select * from yourtable where country_id = 7`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a731/1

Comment: Voted to close as unclear till we get clarification. Comment asked but not answered nor an edit. You only responding to answers??

Comment: I am trying to query all products for a specific filter. Like for product 34 which is set for country 7 and state 1. so if I am going to select this "Select * from products where country_id = 7 and state_id = 1" but for that query I will only get that specific data. I want to query it including the state with a 0 value since that product is not limited on a specific state.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure what you are asking. If you want all products for country 7 and state 0 or 1, this is the query you need: `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE country_id = 7 AND (state_id = 0 OR state_id = 1)`. If this is not what you are looking for please provide exactly the rows you want to be in your output. It's also not clear which values each column can take.

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid yep, that was what I was looking for. I have already implemented that process. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: would be nice if you could upvote my comment since I can't write an answer anymore ;) glad that I helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
where country_id = 7 and
      (state = 1 or state = 0)
```

Normally, I would write this as:

```
where country_id = 7 and state in (0, 1)
```

Comment: based on the above its just `where country_id = 7` as state is all 0\1

Comment: @Dagon read their question again. *"but it will also include all state with an id of 0 since it not assigned on any state"* - Gordon's right on this one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is also same with the other column, right? for the city and area.

Comment: then im confused because the results here are he same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a731/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a731/4

Comment: @banri16 . . . Yes, for each column where you want `0` to be a wildcard.  You only specify that for `state` in the question.

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for product ids which have state id as 1 or 0(no state mentioned).
This mysql query will work for you.

select ProductId from table where country_id = 7 and state_id in (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from yourtable where country_id = 7 and state_id in(1, 0)
```